# Partial Derivative Percentage Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Electrical power $P$ is given by $P = V^2/R$ where $V$ is voltage and $R$ is resistance. Approximate the percentage error in calculating power if the percentage errors in measuring $V$ and $R$ are $2$% and $3$%, respectively.
(Ans:1%)

I found the partial derivative for each variable $V$ and $R$, I also used the chain rule to find $P$ with respect to time. I just can't seem to get the answer from my work to get $1$%.

Comment: Can you show us your work?

Comment: I am strongly suspicious that the answer should be $1\%$. I believe it should be $7\%=2\times 2\%+3\%$. As a rule of thumb, the relative errors add up on either multiplication or division.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time posting a question. Working: https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:81da5c04-a759-4eeb-a875-980374eb6790

Comment: Take a look at the [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about displaying formulas/equations/etc. on this site.